# What YUM is doing after completing process

Tags: yum

For instance when we executed

```
yum update
yum localinstall xyz
```

at the end of process when it shows

```
Complete!
```

and when we execute the next any yum command still it shows

```
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
```

my questions are:

- what type of process it would be doing after displaying final message of complete?
- if we kill this process does it harm to the system?

Comment: have a look to `/var/run/yum.pid` file. Is there any process of yum exist? `ps -lfp \`cat /var/run/yum.pid\``

Comment: At present any `yum` process is not running. But usually it shows the message and I do kill by `kill -9` is it ok?

Comment: What ps shows? It is not ok to kill -9 and it is not ok to see that message about locking.

Comment: Ok I got your point it is not good to `kill` `yum` process. But by doing `ps -lfp cat` will it show details in future, for what and how it is locked?

Comment: It shows the process of yum which handle lock, if it exist. If you, for instance, have several admins and no change managment it could be common situation. If process doesn't exist you can delete lock-file _carefully_ . But if yum does not delete its lock on regular basis, it could be a symptom of serious problem with it.

Comment: I have gone through `ps` syntax: `ps -lfp <PID>` where l means long, f means full and p means process ID. So does it mean that kill will just delete the process file from `/var/run/yum.pid` and terminates yum process?

Comment: `kill` doesn't delete files, and `kill -9` sends the `SIGKILL` signal that can't be ignored or caught by the process, preventing it to do any clean up (of temporary or lock files for instance). If you want to use kill to terminate a process, you should first try `kill -15` (SIGTERM) so that the process will clean up and terminate, unless its really stuck (due to a bug).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see what files a process is using with the tool `lsof`.

#### Example

```
$ sudo lsof -p $(pgrep yum) | head -10
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
yum     5117 root  cwd    DIR              253,2      4096  8921392 /home/saml/tst/134317
yum     5117 root  rtd    DIR              253,1      4096        2 /
yum     5117 root  txt    REG              253,1     11936   556827 /usr/bin/python2.7
yum     5117 root  mem    REG              253,1    277256   538188 /usr/lib64/libsoftokn3.so
yum     5117 root  mem    REG              253,1     43808   534669 /usr/lib64/libcrypt-2.17.so
yum     5117 root  mem    REG              253,1     18168   535410 /usr/lib64/libplds4.so
yum     5117 root  mem    REG              253,1    247464   534827 /usr/lib64/libnspr4.so
yum     5117 root  mem    REG              253,1     22272   534919 /usr/lib64/libplc4.so
yum     5117 root  mem    REG              253,1   1318904   536248 /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
```

When `yum`'s accessing files such as the RPM database:

```
yum     5117 root  mem    REG              253,1   1318912  1313544 /var/lib/rpm/__db.003
yum     5117 root  mem    REG              253,1     90112  1312668 /var/lib/rpm/__db.002
yum     5117 root  mem    REG              253,1    311296  1312467 /var/lib/rpm/__db.001
```

Other processes, including `rpm`, cannot access it either. YUM also makes use of `sqlite` databases, these too are subject to locking, so other processes cannot use them while YUM is.

#### Killing YUM

You can kill it but you'll likely have to do some cleanup afterwards, using `yum-complete-transaction`.

```
$ sudo yum-complete-transaction
$ yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only
```

#### References

- [7.4. yum-complete-transaction](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Software_Management_Guide/ch07s04.html)